$\int_0^\infty \left|\int_x^\infty \cos(2\pi t)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{t+1/4}-\frac{1}{t-1/4}\right) dt \right| dx={}$?
Let $f(t) = \cos(2\pi t)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{t+1/4}-\frac{1}{t-1/4}\right)$. (If you are wondering "why that function?" — it is the Fourier transform of $2\pi \cos(\pi t/2)|_{[-1,1]}$.) The integral $F(x) = \int_x^\infty f(t) dt$ can be written as
$$F(x) = \pi - \mathrm{Si}\left(2\pi x +\pi/2\right) - \mathrm{Si}\left(2\pi x -\pi/2\right).$$
I would like to know the value of
$$I = \int_0^\infty \left|F(x)\right| dx.$$
Now, I can do that numerically, even though rigorous numerical integration of the absolute value of something is a bit of a pain. I wonder, though: can $I$ be expressed as the integral of something without an absolute value in it? Is there, perhaps, even a closed expression (in some sense) for $I$?
(See the related question When is $\int_T^\infty e^{-\delta t} \frac{\cos 2\pi t}{1-t^2} dt = 0$?)

@CarloBeenakker You are right.

I'm not posting this as an answer, because it is unlikely what you are hoping for, but the query "can $I=\int_0^\infty|F(x)|,dx$ be expressed as the integral of something without an absolute value in it", could be answered if you allow for a multiple integral: $$I=(2/\sqrt\pi)\int_0^\infty ,dx\int_0^\infty dt,\exp[-t^2/F(x)].$$

People do hate integrals! And yes, an expression with three integrals nested in it is unlikely to be useful - also, can't one do this with the absolute value of basically anything?

Nobody has to like anything (and not everybody will recognize that this is a meaningful integral that is in some sense representative of a wider class of integrals like it; also, it's well-known among people in verified numerics that taking integrals of absolute values is tricky).

No answer, just numerics, but too long for a comment.
Approximating the integral with the values at the known maxima for large $x>x_\mathrm{m}\in\mathbb{N}$, we get
\begin{align} \tag{1}\label{eq:1}
I = \int_0^{x_\mathrm{m}} |F(x)| \, \mathrm dx + \left[\tfrac 1 2-\tfrac 1 \pi \operatorname{Si}(2\pi x_\mathrm{m})\right]+\mathcal O(x_\mathrm{m}^{-3})\,.
\end{align}
The optimized Mathematica code takes around one minute on my laptop and reads ($x_\mathrm m=1000$)
Accumulate@ParallelTable[{1,NIntegrate[Abs[F[x]],{x,xm-1,xm},WorkingPrecision->60,MaxPoints->2000,MaxRecursion->2000]+(1/2-1/Pi SinIntegral[2 Pi xm])-If[xm>1,(1/2-1/Pi SinIntegral[2 Pi (xm-1)]),0]},{xm,1,1000}] .
A 20th-order polynomial extrapolation of this list gives the value
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
I=0.798074546368928454302900235533322288209658780568820(1) \,.
\end{align}
I don't think that a closed form expression exists.

I'm getting similar numerics, but unfortunately they cannot be included in a proof unless one uses verified numerics (interval arithmetic, ball arithmetic, with rigurous numeric integration). Now, that's tricky, because of the absolute value, but should be doable.
